# Add text to a checkbox switch

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to make a switch with that shows text depending on it's state.

I simplified the code down to this:

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  /*(sliderwidth*2 + left)*/
  width: 72px;
  height: 34px;
}

.slider {  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;  
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.slider:before {
  /*Its the white box*/
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 32px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;

}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  transform: translateX(32px);
  /*must be same as slider width*/
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label>
```

But I am trying to add text to it, like "On" and "Off". I tried doing this:

```
.slider:after {
   content:"Off";
} 
.slider:before {
   content:"On";
}
```

But it displays both of them, and looks really ugly. How can I have just one of the 2 show up?

https://jsfiddle.net/zsm0qkw9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a selector for whether the input is checked or not to only show the relevant label. You actually already have this for changing the color.

Just add to your CSS:

```
input:checked + .slider:after {
   content:"Off";
} 
input:not(:checked) + .slider:before {
   content:"On";
}
```

The `:not` selector just negates the next statement, so when the input is not checked. You can then do further styling of the text here.

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/zsm0qkw9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you use JQuery

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
   var labelStr = this.attr('checked') ? 'On' : 'Off';
   $('slider').attr('data-content', labelStr);
});
```

and  your CSS

```
.slider:after {
    content: attr(data-content)
}
```